# Google Script - Auto Fill Current Date-Time when select specific text in the drop down list

Tags: google-sheets

I wonder if anyone can help me with the following google script? I just begin to work on some google script and help my colleagues to track the production of his work.

Here is the field is explained below.

```
Column 9 = Status (Dropdown list: Pending, In-progress, Done)
Column 11 = Send Date
Column 13 = Start Date
Column 14 = End Date
```

How I want the script work
Example:

- When Column 9 (dropdown list) value = "Pending" then auto fill the current
  date to  Column 11.
- When Column 9 (dropdown list) value = "In-progress" then auto fill
  the current date to Column 13.
- When Column 9 (dropdown list) value = "End Date" then auto fill the current
  date to Column 14.

The code I am working on to get when the status is "In-Progress".
I know I am wrong about this part. -> [s.getValue() !== 'In-progress']
But I am not sure where or how to put the certain text that I am looking for in here.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
    cols = [9],
    colStamp = 13,
    ind = cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
    if (s.getName() !== 'Lab Cases Tracker' || s.getValue() !== 'In-progress' || ind == -1) return;
e.range.offset(0, parseInt(colStamp - cols[ind]))
    .setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s1=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var s = e.source.getSheetName()
  var col=e.range.getColumn()
  var r=e.range.getRow()
  var val=e.value
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
  if(s=="Lab Cases Tracker" && col==9){
    if(val=="Pending"){
      s1.getRange(r,11,1,1).setValue(curDate);
    }
  else if(val=="In-progress"){
      s1.getRange(r,13,1,1).setValue(curDate);
    }
  else if(val=="End Date"){
      s1.getRange(r,14,1,1).setValue(curDate);
    }
  else{return} 
 }}
```

Comment: I've change  
var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM/dd/yyyy")
to
var curDate = new Date()

Comment: Hope the other found this useful!